# Images for after clicking on suboption from the popup window remains as it is in selenium

Tags: selenium

In my application left-hand side menu bar which contain 8 modules of an application. And each of module contain suboptions.
I am trying to click on one of suboption from a particular module which having 30 suboptions(pages).
But after clicking on a particular option the popup window remains as it is on screen and it does not allow me to click the options which are behind the popup screen.
Behind popup screen the dropdown option is there and want to select one option from that dropdown.
Its giving me an error "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite."
Here is the code
`//div[@id='main-nav']/ul`  --Gives me 6 modules name(6 ul):

```
 <ul class="main-nav-gray-border user-details-menu-tab left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul" xpath="1"></ul>
    <ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul" xpath="2">
    <li class="main-nav-img-label" id="admin-nav">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="main-nav-icons"></svg>
    <label>
    Analytics
    </label>
    <ul class="nav-items admin-menu-items" style="top: 50px;" id="admin-menu-items">
    <li class="side-nav-titles"></li>
    <a class="module-item-child  selected-nav-item" href="#" id="QualityMeasures37" onclick="loadModule('Analytics/Index?dashboardUrlId=71', 2,'QualityMeasures', 37,null,'Quality Measures')" xpath="1">
    <li>**Quality Measures**</li>
     </a>
    <a class="module-child "  id="QualityMainView38" onclick="loadModule('Analytics/Index?dashboardUrlId=93', 2,'QualityMainView', 38,null,'Quality Main View')"></a>
    <a class="module-child "  id="QualityRanking39" onclick="loadModule('Analytics/Index?dashboardUrlId=94', 2,'QualityRanking', 39,null,'Quality Ranking')"></a>
    <a class="module-child "  id="QualityTrending40" onclick="loadModule('Analytics/Index?dashboardUrlId=95', 2,'QualityTrending', 40,null,'Quality Trending')"></a>
    <a class="module-child user-default-module selected-nav-item" href="#" id="DetailedFinanceAndUtilization41" onclick="loadModule('Analytics/Index?dashboardUrlId=76', 2,'DetailedFinanceAndUtilization', 41,null,'Detailed Finance &amp; Utilization')"></a>
    <a class="module-child "  id="DetailedFinanceandUtilizationPro42" onclick="loadModule('Analytics/Index?dashboardUrlId=77', 2,'DetailedFinanceandUtilizationPro', 42,null,'Detailed Finance &amp; Utilization Professional')"></a>
    <a class="module-child "  id="PartAClaimsAnalysis43" onclick="loadModule('Analytics/Index?dashboardUrlId=87', 2,'PartAClaimsAnalysis', 43,null,'Facility Claims Analysis')"></a>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul" xpath="3"></ul>
    <ul class="icon-minimizer" id="minimizer-nav" xpath="7"></ul>
```

This the code for a drop down menu.

```
<div class="dd-select" style="width: 100px; background: rgb(245, 245, 245);" xpath="1">
<input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" value="Level1"><a class="dd-selected"><label class="dd-selected-text" title="Enterprise">Enterprise</label></a>
<span class="dd-pointer dd-pointer-down"></span></div>
```

This is the code to select the option from drop down menu.

```
<div id="SelectedHierarchyLevelName" class="dd-container" style="width: 100px;" xpath="1">
<div class="dd-select" style="width: 100px; background: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
<input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" value="Level3">
<a class="dd-selected">
<label class="dd-selected-text" title="Facility">**Facility**</label></a>
<span class="dd-pointer dd-pointer-down dd-pointer-up"></span></div>
<ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close" style="min-width: 100px; height: 150px; overflow: auto; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176) 0px 6px 16px; display: block;">

<li class=""><a class="dd-option"> <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="Level1"> <label class="dd-option-text">Enterprise</label></a></li>
<li class=""><a class="dd-option"> <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="Level2"> <label class="dd-option-text">Ministry</label></a></li>
<li class=""><a class="dd-option dd-option-selected"> <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="Level3"> <label class="dd-option-text">Facility</label></a></li>
<li class=""><a class="dd-option"> <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="Level4"> <label class="dd-option-text">Med Group/Division</label></a></li>
<li class="hideMe"><a class="dd-option"> <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="Missing Providers"> <label class="dd-option-text">Missing Providers</label></a></li>
<li class=""><a class="dd-option"> <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="Help"> <label class="dd-option-text">Help</label></a></li>

<li class="hideMe"><a class="dd-option"> <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="L0Simulation"> <label class="dd-option-text">Unknown Simulation</label></a></li></ul></div>
```

I tried following:

```
@FindBy(id="admin-nav")
    WebElement mouseHover;
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@id='QualityMeasures37']//li[contains(text(),'Quality Measures')]")
    WebElement btnQualityMeasure;
    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@id='SelectedHierarchyLevelName']//span[@class='dd-pointer dd-pointer-down']")
    WebElement dropDown;
    @FindBy(xpath="//label[contains(text(),'Facility')]")
    WebElement facilityOption;

public void hoverTest() throws Exception    
 {
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(mouseHover).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
//      ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", btnQualityMeasure);
//      Thread.sleep(1000);
        act.moveToElement(btnQualityMeasure).click().build().perform(); //clicking on suboption
        Thread.sleep(10500);
    }

    public void clickDropDownButton()   
    {
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(dropDown).click().build().perform();
    }

    public void selectFromDropDown() throws Exception{
        Actions act1 = new Actions(driver);
//      ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ministryOption);
//      Thread.sleep(1000);
        act1.moveToElement(ministryOption).click().build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
```

//The first method Mousehover it and select the desired suboption.
Second method clicking on dropdown button and 3rd method selecting the option from drop down.
In short from the 'Analytics' module the suboption 'Quality Measure' should be select  and on that page click on one drop down menu and select the option 'Facility'. I highlighted as bold all 3 in my above code.
Its giving me an eroor "Its giving me an error "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite." 
Also some time it does not open the desired suboption.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest using WebDriverWaits for the elements to be clickable.  (Seems like javascript is firing on hover to populate...)  You can lose the sleep at that point. I wouldn't think you'd need the scroll or the actions for the click.  element.click should scroll and click the element you want:  https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#element-click  Not sure why the javascript error is being thrown, but you shouldn't need to do that anyway.

Comment: If i just execute the hovertest() method, its clicking on desired object.

Comment: @pcalkins, please help me out, i got stuck

Comment: I think part of the problem is when you are locating the objects.  I'm not familiar with those @FindBy tags... but it seems like some objects won't be there when you are looking for them? (or does it find when the variable is used?) Use WebDriverWaits to find the elements after opening the new menus.

Comment: For a time being i used thread.sleep() to wait.

Comment: For the pulldown, the span tag is empty so I wouldn't think you'd have an event handler there... without seeing the scripts used it's hard to tell, but you may need to target the <a> tag, or even the <label>...  You should also start catching errors to see which elements are actually being found.

Comment: Tried with different path as you suggested,  and removed the doubleclick . Now got an error "org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable" while clicking on the option from dropdown, its actually not clicking on drop down button

Comment: that means the element probably does not have an event handler... do you have a URL we could look at?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204231/discussion-between-appi-and-pcalkins).